# Explicit Conversion Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am developing web APIs, I am getting an error while returning data;

> Cannot Implicitly Convert type

I tried fixing an error but failed, let me have some help from great developers like you. I will appreciate.
Below is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<TABLE1> LoadSubIndustryByID(int id)
{
    foreach (var subIndustry in Db.TABLE1.Where((u) => u.us_user_id == id))
    {
        var childIndustry = Db.TABLE2.Where((c) => c.sci_cat_id == subIndustry.sci_cat_id);
        yield return childIndustry;
    }
}
```

This statement: `yield return childIndustry;` gives an error, other statements are fine. Actually it complain only for `childIndustry`.

Comment: Because `childIndustry` is `IEnumerable<TABLE2>` but your method is returning `IEnumerable<TABLE1>`. You should change the method's return type to `IEnumerable<TABLE2>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning `IEnumerable` of TABLE1 while you are yielding type of TABLE2.

You should change function to return `IEnumerable<TABLE2>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<TABLE2> LoadSubIndustryByID(int id)
{
    foreach (var subIndustry in Db.TABLE1.Where((u) => u.us_user_id == id))
    {

        var childIndustry = Db.TABLE2.Where((c) => c.sci_cat_id == subIndustry.sci_cat_id);

        yield return childIndustry;
    }
}
```

This will work.